# Invert Cubic Bezier Curve

Tags: inverse, bezier-curve

I am trying to 'invert' a path.
`Lines` are fairly easy as they just need to be multiplied by `-1`, however, I am struggling to convert the bezier curve path into its inverse.

The relevant code is:

```
c0,0,1.628,34.086-32.059,34.086
c-33.688,0-32.059-34.086-32.059-34.086
```

where `c` denotes the start of a new curve.

For clarification purposes, `inverse` means that if the curve is starting from right to left, then after inverse, it would start from left to right & vice versa.

[Here is a link.](https://jsbin.com/hetomu/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 3):

Your clarification does not clarify (for me, at least). I still don't know what you mean by "invert".

If you want to "flip" the curve (mirror it about a vertical line), then negate the x-coordinates of all the control points.

If you want to reverse the direction of the curve (trace out the same curve, but in the opposite direction), then just reverse the order of the control points.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you ask, it should be quite simple: to invert horizontally multiply by $-1$ (of course we are using relative coordinates) all the first coordinate of every couple.

Example: the inverse of `c 1 2 3 4 5 6` should be `c -1 2 -3 4 -5 6`.

At least I hope this is what you are asking for.